# JavaScript handle JSON array all in [0] after first loop

Tags: javascript, json

```
  localContentSet.forEach((child) => {
                    // console.log("child------->");
                    // console.log(child);
                    // console.log("child.contents------->");
                    // console.log(child[0]);
                    **let contents = child[0] == null? child.contents: child[0].contents;**
                        contents.forEach((content) => {

                            console.log(content);

                        });

                });
```

hi, all, I have a JSON array has 10 elements in each Object, I found if you were using forEach, all the elements will be put in [0], after the first Object.

the json looks like:

```
[
 {
   element1:value,
   element2:value,
   element3:value,
   element4:value,
   element5:value,
   ...
 },
 {
   element1:value,
   element2:value,
   element3:value,
   element4:value,
   element5:value,
   ...
 }
  ...
]
```

Any idea about how it is please?

Comment: Please specify what effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: what is contents? can you clean up your code?

Answer (score 0):

with foreach you can not use `child[0]` try directly `child` you will get data in `child`.

if you want that your data must come with `array` means `child[0]` than use for loop

Comment: but please, if we use child[0] , the first loop will be failed, that is the reason I put let contents = child[0] == null? child.contents: child[0].contents; where means the first loop is correct.